# Chrome Extension manifest.json not loading permissions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a small chrome extension to make life at work a bit easier, but I'm running into a small issue. Chrome is reading manifest.json fine with no errors but I'm not getting the requested permission.

I tried to changing the manifest.json around and reloading the extension, other fields such as the title and version updated fine, but its as if there is no permissions field in the file and chrome is telling me that the 'extension requires no special permissions'

```
{
  "name": "Eluta Tools",
  "description": "copy/paste harvesters - work smarter",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "storage"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

I thought it was an issue with my personal machine and tried it on a different one with the same result. I had this working fine last night so I'm wondering, what mistake am I making?!?

Full code at my [github](https://github.com/RabinSamaroo/eluta-chrome-ext)

Comment: The observed behavior is correct. Those permissions aren't special.